# Camera Calibration using OpenCV2 and Python 2.7 / cv2.findChessboardCorners

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to do a multipectral camera calibration using **Open Cv2** and **Python 2.7**, and the code is working well with the pictures that I have from the 3 monochrome sensors (RED, NIR, and GRE) and the RGB ones. The only pictures that are not working in the code are the pictures from the REG sensor (Red Green).

The code **reads the pictures**, **converts them to gray** and then **finds the corners**, **the SubPixels**, and finally producres a **camera calibration matrix**.

I have built the code with multiple print in each part so that I will know which is the exact part that is not working, so I know that it is not working for the REG case in the **cv2.findChessboardCorners** line.

```
    ret, Bords_Trouves = cv2.findChessboardCorners(Images_en_gris, Lignes_et_Collones, None)
```

So my question is :

What's not working in the code ? Or is it a problem with the REG sensor pictures, I would have to try another approach to convert them to gray ? Or what ?

Here is all the code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import math
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


critere = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.01)

Lignes = 13
Collones = 13
Collones_et_Lignes = (Collones, Lignes)
Lignes_et_Collones = (Lignes, Collones)

Points_Reels = np.zeros((Lignes*Collones, 3), np.float32)
Points_Reels[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:Lignes, 0:Collones].T.reshape(-1, 2)

# Préparer deux tableaux pour sauvegarder les points objet et points images de totues les images trouvées.
Tableau_points_reels = []
Tableau_points_imaginaires = []

# Les photos du damier qu'on a pris pour le test
Source = "C:/Users/Mourad/Desktop/Calib1804/REG/"
Mes_Images = glob.glob(Source + '*.TIF')

print "les images ont bien étaient récupérées." if Mes_Images else "PROBLEME: images non récupérés !! "

for leo, fname in enumerate(Mes_Images):
    print("Image : " + fname)
    #if leo > 10:
     # break
    image_originale = cv2.imread(fname)

    Images_en_gris = cv2.cvtColor(image_originale, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    print "les images ont bien étaient transformés en gris." if Images_en_gris.all() else "PROBLEME: images non transformés en gris!! "

    ret, Bords_Trouves = cv2.findChessboardCorners(Images_en_gris, Lignes_et_Collones, None)

    print str(len(Bords_Trouves)) + " Bords trouvés" if ret else "PROBLEME: Bords Non trouvés !!"

    Tableau_points_reels.append(Points_Reels)

    PL = (11, 11)

    Plus_de_precision = cv2.cornerSubPix(Images_en_gris, Bords_Trouves[1], PL, (-1, -1), critere)


    print "Sub pixels trouvées" if Plus_de_precision else "PROBLEME: Pas de sub pixels trouvées"

    Tableau_points_imaginaires.append(Bords_Trouves)

   # far = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(image_originale, Lignes_et_Collones, Bords_Trouves, ret)

    #cv2.imshow("Bords trouvées déssinés sur l'image originale", image_originale)
    #cv2.waitKey(500)
    #()
print "Nombre de points réels trouvés: " + str(len(Tableau_points_reels))
print "Nombres de points imaginaires trouvés: " + str(len(Tableau_points_imaginaires))

h, w = Images_en_gris.shape[:2]

derik, matrice, distortion, vecteur_de_rotation, vecteur_de_translation = cv2.calibrateCamera(Tableau_points_reels, Tableau_points_imaginaires, (w, h), None, None, flags=cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL)

print "La matrice de calibration est: "
print matrice
print "La distortion est egale a: "
print distortion
print "Le vecteur de rotation est egal a: "
print vecteur_de_rotation
print "Le vecteur de translation est egal a: "
print vecteur_de_translation

print "\n La matrice de calibration trouvée et données récupérés" if derik else "PROBLEME: Pas de calibration"

newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(matrice, distortion, (w, h), 1, (w, h))

# undistortion
Image_calibree = cv2.undistort(image_originale, matrice, distortion, None, newcameramtx)

fgh = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Mourad/Desktop/Calib1804/RGB/IMG_700101_000800_0000_RGB.JPG")

h, w = fgh.shape[:2]

x, y, w, h = roi
Image_calibree = Image_calibree[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite('Desktop/imagecalibre.png', Image_calibree)

plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(fgh), plt.title('image originale')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(Image_calibree), plt.title('image calibree')
plt.show()

Erreur_totale = 0
for i in xrange(len(Tableau_points_reels)):
    imgpoints2, _ = cv2.projectPoints(Tableau_points_reels[i], vecteur_de_rotation[i], vecteur_de_translation[i], matrice, distortion)
    Erreur = cv2.norm(Tableau_points_imaginaires[i], imgpoints2, cv2.NORM_L2)/len(imgpoints2)
    Erreur_totale += Erreur
    print "Erreur totale: ", Erreur_totale/len(Tableau_points_reels)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

If that same piece of code worked for the images from other sensors there has to be something wrong with the pictures you hand to `cv2.findChessboardCorners`.

Try visualizing the images with `cv2.imshow` before the go into the function. Probably the color conversion is wrong because with `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` a 3-channel image is converted to grayscale but you should have two channels, if I understood your format right.

`cv2.findChessboardCorners` should also work with color images so the easiest solution may just be skipping the color conversion if that's what messes up your images.